# Process Loading into Main Memory(RAM)

Tags: memory-management, process, operating-system, scheduling

My query is: A process comes to ready queue( Is the ready queue a data structure in RAM?) and then the loader creates space for the process in main memory after which it is loaded in that allocated space. My doubts are: when a process is in ready queue and not yet gone through the process of loading, is it actually in main memory or in secondary storage? If the ready queue is in main memory which means the process is also in main memory then after loading, we are basically moving a process from one part of main memory(ready queue) to some other part!! Or is it like we only have the metadata of a process in ready queue and only after loading we'll have the complete process into the main memory?

In OS Principles by Silberschatz and Galvin, it is saying that the after a process enters into the system, it is kept into ready queue and then OS takes into account the memory requirements of the process. When a process is allocated memory, it is being loaded into main memory. My doubt is : where does the ready queue exists and what exactly it contains about the process? Is the content of of a process in ready queue different than what we have after loading?

Comment: Typically, the OS queues contain pointers to Thread Control Blocks which keep a pointer to the Process Control Block.  A lot of kernel activity involves moving items between queues, so pointer queues are efficient - no need to move around anything larger.  A double-linked list can also be used, with each TCB having a pair of pointers to link onto a queue, but this introduces problems when a TCB needs to be in more than one queue.